# Android Studio | Waiting some time before the next Activity shows up (Startscreen)

Tags: java, android, android-activity, wait, seconds

i want that, when i start my App, a startscreen shows of for 3 seconds and then  i want the app to jump automaticly to the next Activity.

I am a beginner at Android Studio so it would be nice if you can explain what it does.

I do not have any code refering to this to show you :(

Thanks a lot

Comment: i think you can take a look at splash screens: https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/splash-screens-the-right-way/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(CURRRENTACTIVITY.this, YOURSECONDACTIVITY.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
  }
}, 3000);
```

add this code to the onCreate or onResume method of your first activity after 3sec it will show up your second activity!

Comment: it throws an error at ...(this, MainActivity.class)

Comment: sorry, check it now!it should work

Comment: thank you for the fast and short help :) it worked out fine

Comment: your welcome! if it works then you should mark it as correct answer!